# Weird output when using fork()

Tags: c, linux, process

I am trying to create a time-based pool: you either give an answer to all the questions or the time's up. My original logic was to get a child to count and the parent to ask questions, but I failed to implement that. Thus, I decided to create 2 children and let the parent orchestrate their behavior.

The first child counts the time, while the second child asks the questions. It seems to be working, except at the end of the program, the remaining questions get printed as well, which is kinda weird. My guess is that the scanf's still wait for me to press some key, then it floods the console with junk.

Now, for some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int askQuestions(char* array[], int size){
    char* answer;
    for(int i =0 ; i < size ; i ++){
        printf("%s\n",array[i]);
        scanf("%s",&answer);
    }
    return 0;
}

int count(int bound){
    int index = 0;
    printf("Counting started....\n");


    while(index < bound){
        sleep(1);
        index++;
        printf("%d seconds left \n", bound-index);
    }

    printf("Time's up!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char* questions[] = {"Q1","Q2","Q3"};
    int size = sizeof(questions)/sizeof(questions[0]);
    int countingTime = 3;
    int status;
    pid_t id1,id2;

    id1 = fork();
    if(id1 < 0){
        printf("Fork failed");
    }else{

        if(id1 == 0){
            status = count(countingTime);
            exit(status);
        }else{
            id2 = fork();
            if(id2 == 0){
                status = askQuestions(questions,size);
                exit(status);
            }
        } 
         wait(0);  
    }



    return 0;

}
```

Output looks like this:

```
Counting started....
Q1
2 seconds left
1 seconds left
0 seconds left
Time's up!
[modan@HP15-ManjaroCinnamon Test]$ Q2
Q3
```

P.S. the processes definitely stop. (checked it via top)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you responding to the question?

Comment: the function `askQuestions()`  prints out ALL the questions and retrieves all the answers (into the 'answer' array) with out allowing the program to process any of the answers

Comment: regarding: `char* answer; ... scanf("%s",&answer);` this results in a pointer to a pointer being passed the %s format specifier, which is expecting a a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. Suggest: `char answer[128]; ... scanf("%s", answer);` Notice no `&` for the parameter being passed to `scanf()`

Comment: suggest rewriting the `count()` function using the fuction `setitimer()`  and using a `signal` to catch the expiration of the timer

Comment: regarding: `printf("Fork failed");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Strongly suggest using: `perror( "Fork failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  which will output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  This as the side benefit that the `else { ... }`  can be reduced to only the `...`

Comment: when calling the function: `fork()`  there are three possible outcomes.  On the second call to `fork()`, the posted code is not handling all three possible outcomes

Comment: if `questions[]` were to be terminated with a NULL entry, then the `size` variable and all associated usage of that variable could be eliminated.  Then the function: `askQuestions()` could simply be checking for that NULL entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only calling `wait()` once. So the parent process only waits for one child to exit, not both of them, then exits itself and the other child keeps running. In your case, the  child that does the countdown finishes first, so the child that prints the questions keeps running after the parent process exits.

Meanwhile, the shell is only waiting for the parent process. When it exits, the shell prints the next prompt. That's why you see questions printed after the prompt.

You should call `wait()` in a loop:

```
while (wait(0) != -1) {
}
```

It will return `-1` when there are no children available to wait for, then the loop will end.

You should also fix the pointer problem that @NPE mentioned, but that's not the direct reason for the strange output.

Comment: @CyberFox I added another detail about the shell printing the prompt as soon as the parent process exits. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the `scanf()`:

```
char* answer;
...
scanf("%s",&answer);
```

1. `&answer` should read `answer`.
2. You never allocate memory for `answer` in the first place.

This gives rise to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning that your program is perfectly within its right to do whatever it pleases. :)

(Thanks to `@EugeneSh.` for pointing out the missing ampersand!)

Comment: Worth adding that the `&` is misplaced here even if the space was allocated.

Comment: Note that the undefined behavior only happens if he types something in response to the question. No answer is shown in the transcript.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but I doubt that it is the source of my troubles.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you'd want to *kill* the other subprocess after the time is up (or kill the timer if questions are answered);

And exit only after having `wait`ed until `-1` is returned with `ECHILD` in `errno` (*all* children waited for).

Answer (score 2):

The other posts already pointed out the problems in your code.

I am just showing an alternative way of doing, what you want to do, using [**select()**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define TIMER_IN_SECS 3

int main(void) {
    char* questions[] = {"Q1","Q2","Q3"};
    char answer[50] = {0};
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval = 0;
    int read_bytes = 0;
    time_t start = 0;
    time_t curr = 0;
    time_t remain = 0;

    /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    start = time(NULL);
    printf("You have %d seconds of time and your time start now..\n", TIMER_IN_SECS);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(questions)/sizeof(questions[0]); i++) {
        curr = time(NULL);
        if ((remain = (TIMER_IN_SECS - (curr - start))) <= 0) {
            printf("Timeout!!! %d seconds are over\n", TIMER_IN_SECS);
            break;
        }

        printf ("%s\n", questions[i]);

        /* Wait up to remaining seconds. */
        tv.tv_sec = remain;
        retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (retval == -1) {
            perror("select()");
            return -1;
        } 

        if (retval) {
            read_bytes = read(0, answer, 49);
            if (read_bytes == -1) {
                perror("read()");
                return -1;
            }
            if(answer[read_bytes-1] == '\n') {
                --read_bytes;
                answer[read_bytes] = '\0';
            }
            /* In case if user just pressed enter key to skip the question */
            if(read_bytes == 0) {
                printf("No input..\n");
            } else {
                printf("Answer given by you : %s\n", answer);
            }
        } else {
            printf("Timeout!!! %d seconds are over\n", TIMER_IN_SECS);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./mytimer
You have 3 seconds of time and your time start now..
Q1
ss
Answer given by you : ss
Q2
ff
Answer given by you : ff
Q3
e
Answer given by you : e

# ./mytimer
You have 3 seconds of time and your time start now..
Q1
tt
Answer given by you : tt
Q2
d
Answer given by you : d
Q3
Timeout!!! 3 seconds are over

# ./mytimer
You have 3 seconds of time and your time start now..
Q1
d
Answer given by you : d
Timeout!!! 3 seconds are over
```

Comment: This quite a fancy implementation, but I really want to get more into fork().